# Sequences where average equals median

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Define $S_n$ as the set ${1,2,\dots,n}$. A non-empty subset $T_n$ of $S_n$ is called $balanced$ if the average of the elements of $T_n$ is equal to the median of $T_n$. Prove that, for all $n$, the number of balanced subsets $T_n$ is odd.$\;$*(CMO 2017;P3)*

I proceeded to consider a corresponding binary sequence where $0$ and $1$ indicate if the element belong to the required sequence or not,respectively.
Some sequences must be symmetric about the midpoint.Like for example in $$\{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$$

$$1 \;0 \;1 \;0 \;1$$ forms $\{1,3,5\}$

But there are some sub-sequences which are not of this form, like $\{3,4,5\} \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ corresponding to $0\,0\,1\,1\,1$ and likewise in $\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ we have to eliminate $0\;0\;0\;0\;0\;0$ but count $0\;0\;0\;1\;1\;1$ ($\equiv \{3,4,5\}$).

*How can I establish a bijection between these sets?*

Answer (score 2):

As $n-1-A=\{n+1-a|a\in A\}$ is balanced for any balanced $A$, we may pair off non-palindromic balanced subsets of $S_n$. Every palindromic subset of $S_n$ is clearly balanced, so it suffices to show that there are an odd number of palindromic subsets of $S_n$. Note that every palindromic subset is the union of a nonzero number of sets from  $\{1,n\},\{2,n-1\},\ldots,\left\{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor,\left\lceil\frac {n+1}2\right\rceil\right\}$, so there are $2^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor}-1$ palindromic subsets of $S_n$. This is odd as $\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor>0$ for all positive integers $n$, as desired.